# How to refer to nested objects with "-" in the name

Tags: javascript, object, jsfiddle

I am having trouble referring to any variables with "-" in the variable name. I feel the answer is something very simple but I can't figure it out.

For Example

```js
var headers = {
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  "content-length": "261",
  "connection": "close",
  "date": "Fri, 01 Apr 2022 09:12:56 GMT",
  "server": "nginx",
  "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
  "x-mbx-uuid": "88911a02-ff75-4cc0-b8ef-1ea4ab0edabd",
  "x-mbx-used-weight": "10",
  "x-mbx-used-weight-1m": "10"
}
```

to refer to an element, the following works

```js
console.log(headers.server)
```

But the following doesnt work because javascript doesn't recognise - . How do I refer to `x-mbx-used-weight-1m` in this case?

```js
console.log(headers.x-mbx-used-weight-1m)
```

[image: You can see it is not recognised in JSFiddle]

Comment: Use `headers['x-mbx-used-weight-1m']`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use square brackets and quote marks:

```
headers["x-mbx-used-weight-1m"]
```